# If a row is not NaN then the first two rows of that column should be merged with the none NaN value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this dataset that has several nan values but when its cleaned the first two rows should from the column 2 should on the same row with a price.
I removed the NaN values in the first row after I noticed a pattern, below is a code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
four = pd.read_excel('4.-Badly-Structured-Sales-Data-4.xlsx', header = None)
four.iloc[0] = four.iloc[0].fillna(method='ffill')
four
```

\n
The dirty data looks like this

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nan | Ship Mode | First Class | First Class | Same Day | Same Day | Second Class | Second Class |
| nan | Segment | Consumer | Corporate | Consumer | Corporate | Consumer | Corporate |
| Order ID | Order Date | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| CA-2011-100293 | 2013-03-14 00:00:00 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 35.56 |
| CA-2011-111293 | 2013-07-14 00:00:00 | NaN | NaN | 23.679 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| CA-2011-130294 | 2013-03-12 00:00:00 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 65.33 | NaN | NaN |
| CA-2011-167293 | 2013-05-22 00:00:00 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 45.56 |
| CA-2011-100253 | 2013-03-23 00:00:00 | 127.44 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| CA-2011-100231 | 2013-02-14 00:00:00 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 568.333 | NaN | NaN |
| CA-2011-156223 | 2013-08-14 00:00:00 | NaN | 593.11 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| CA-2011-100719 | 2013-03-28 00:00:00 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 37.3 | NaN |

I have tried to use an IF statement that

```
for i,j in four.iterrows():
    if i != 'NaN':
        print(four.iloc[0] + str(i))
```

but its not giving what i want. the cleaned data should look something like this and don't really worry about the date column
[image: clean]

please help

Comment: Is possible share data in excel by dropbox, gdocs,... ? Because hard test MulitIndex here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is create `MultiIndex` in columns and indices, how do it depends of data in excel. Here is first idea:

```
df = pd.read_excel('4.-Badly-Structured-Sales-Data-4.xlsx', header = [0,1], index_col=[0,1])
```

Last reshape:

```
df = (df.stack([0,1])
        .rename_axis(['Order ID','Order Date','Ship Mode','Segment'])
        .reset_index(name='Sales'))
```

Comment: OMG, it worked, it actually worked, how. thank you but how.